# Join list of lists into a delimiter separated list of lists

Tags: python

I have the following list of lists and a delimiter:

```
lsts = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
delim = ['delim']
```

I'd like to mimic the `string.join()` behavior.

**expected output is:**

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3], ['delim'], [4, 5], ['delim'], [6]]
```

**I tried:**

```
from itertools import chain
n = 2
ele = 'x'
lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
list(chain(*[lst[i:i+n] + [ele] if len(lst[i:i+n]) == n else lst[i:i+n] for i in xrange(0, len(lst), n)]))
# which flattens the list and then inserst elements every second position,
# which doesn't help if the lists inside the list are of different length.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use slice assignment

```
def list_join(seq, delim):
    res = [delim]*(len(seq) * 2 - 1)
    res[::2] = seq
    return res

delim = ['delim']
# empty list
lsts = [[]]
print(list_join(lsts, delim))

# even length
lsts = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7]]
print(list_join(lsts, delim))

# odd length
lsts = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
print(list_join(lsts, delim))
```

Output

```
[[]]
[[1, 2, 3], ['delim'], [4, 5], ['delim'], [6], ['delim'], [7]]
[[1, 2, 3], ['delim'], [4, 5], ['delim'], [6]]
```

Comment: I think this way is better

Comment: Thank you very much, I wasn't aware of the `res[::2] = seq` part. Learned something new +1

Comment: accepted, this answer even though its more complicated, because it handels empty `lsts` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
lsts = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
delim = ['delim']
place_holder = []

for i in lsts:
    place_holder.append(i)
    place_holder.append(delim)

place_holder.pop() # Pop the last element :)
print(place_holder)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very simple and good to understand and to read. +1

Comment: @Andreas You can upvote it and select as the answer if you like :) Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I upvoted already, I also almost accepted your answer because it was mcuh simpler than the alternatives, but it has one problem. It seems to crash in case of an empty `lsts` otherwise it would have been perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution. It looks like the shortest code.

```
for i in range(len(lsts) - 1, 0, -1):
    lsts.insert(i, delim)

print(lsts)
```

Comment: But it cannot run, man! It is lsts, not lst!

Answer (score 1):

This uses a simple for loop that validates the position on the item isn’t the last item before adding the delimiter.

```py
lsts = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
delim = ['delim']

output = []
for i, l in enumerate(lsts):
    output.append(l)
    if i < (len(lsts) - 1):
        output.append(delim)
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying to solve it for quite a while and reviewing the other answers, I came up with an other alternative as well.

```
lsts = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]]
delim = ['delim']

[x for t in zip(lsts,[delim]*len(lsts)) for x in t][:-1]

# Out[44]: [[1, 2, 3], ['delim'], [4, 5], ['delim'], [6]]
```